# Android layout: first element at the bottom, rest available below after scrolling

Tags: android, android-layout

[image]I would like to achieve following result with a layout:

1) most of the view is empty;

2) first element is at the bottom of what is visible of the screen

3) there are following elements below the first one available through scrolling down.

Is it possible to achieve that?

Maybe I can achieve it through some empty placeholder at the top? How I make it fill all the space available on the screen, but not to go over the first element?

Comment: Add some fig about what you want..

Comment: Place your first element in a FrameLayout. It will be above your empty place holder.

Comment: Pankaj: I added a picture. Naddy: Could you elaborate on how I should do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to achieve this using padding on the first element and moving it the bottom of the screen. I had to set up the padding programmatically after the initial layout is drawn and sizes of all views are known.

Answer (score 0):

Following xml will show first element at the bottom of the page and on scroll next elements can be accessed.

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ScrollView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="@android:color/darker_gray" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical" >

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:text="TEXT1" />
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

   </RelativeLayout>
```

Let me know this solves your problem :-)

Comment: Close, but that's not exactly what I want. I would like the elements to start filling up the empty of the screen, as I start scrolling up. Right now they only occupy the small slice at the bottom.

Comment: Basically, I would like to have a list of elements that is scrollable, but the first element is initially displayed at the bottom of the screen.